# Where is the Docker JSON file logging driver writing files to?

Tags: logging, docker

I have Dockerized a sample app and have configured it to log to STDOUT. I then run the container without specifying a `logging-driver`. According to the Docker docs, STDOUT should be collected out of the container and into a JSON file...

But nowhere in the [logging docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) do they tell you where you can find this JSON file!!!

Any ideas how I could find this file on my host and inspect its contents?

Comment: I'm confused, from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/json-file/): "*By default, Docker captures the standard output (and standard error) of all your containers, and writes them in files using the JSON format.*" How am I misreading that? I am logging to STDOUT/console, and expect (based on all the docs I've read including that blurb above) Docker to collect STDOUT/console out of my container and write it to a file somewhere on my host. I'm wondering where that file is on my host.

Comment: See [View a container's logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`docker inspect` is your friend to figure out details regarding a container. With this you can get the log path by running following command:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' NAME|ID
```

For example:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' 2de7566c47eb
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Qasim (+1) - when I do a `docker ps` I see my container ID is `a6bd3a849fc0`, and so when I run `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' a6bd3a849fc0` I get `/var/lib/docker/containers/some-enormous-alphanumerical-num-json.log`.

Comment: And when I go to tail that log file (`tail -f /var/lib/docker/containers/some-enormous-alphanumerical-num-‌​json.log)` the tail gives me `No such file or directory.` Sure enough, when I check the file system, that file doesn't exist. What's up with that?! BTW I'm running Docker for Mac...but hopefully that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @smeeb In case of Mac/Windows this path were refer to the path in docker machine node. So you can find it in the VM.  But in this case I would prefer using `docker logs a6bd3a849fc0` using which you can also follow the container logs using `docker logs -f a6bd3a849fc0`. Let me know if it doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: In the case of Docker for Mac, to find the JSON file returned from `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' NAME|ID`, first use command `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty` then you'll be able to `cat JSON_PATH_HERE`

Comment: @givemesnacks, i still don't see the path, its still No such file or directory