# Why does Fluent-bit use the varlibdockercontainers volume?

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

There is an official manifest for the deployment of the daemonset https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/output/elasticsearch/fluent-bit-ds.yaml

Line 49 defines the volume `varlibdockercontainers`.

I don't understand why the Fluent-bit needs to read data from the folder `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

Comment: Note that soon Kubernetes will stop using and supporting Docker. Containerd is not using `/var/lib/docker/containers`. So in the future, or if you are already using containerd, this mount will not be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why the Fluent-bit needs to read data from the folder `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

Because that is where docker stores its `${container_id}-json.log` file when using the [`json-file` logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/), which is (AFAIK) the default. There are more details [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579227/where-is-the-docker-json-file-logging-driver-writing-files-to)

Therefore, in order for fluent to transmit logs, it does (effectively) `tail -f $the_log_filename | jq -r .log` and those are the container's logs. If you want to see the *actual* implementation, it seems to be in [`docker.h`](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/v1.8.10/plugins/in_docker/docker.h#L40) and its `docker.c` peer